# NoResponse Received - Smack MUC Presence (entering the room)

Tags: java, android, ejabberd, smack

I am trying to send the presence in the MUC room (to enter/join the room after being offline for some days) with the following code, however, this doesn't return any response from the server. Is that something messed in code?

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                presence.setTo(App.utility.getJID(App.mContext, App.utility.getFullRoomId(groupName) + "/" + nickIdUser));
                presence.addExtension(new MUCInitialPresence("", -1, -1, -1, null));
                MyXMPP.connection.sendStanza(presence);
```

Comment: You can try this to investigate your problem: install a well-known XMPP desktop client, like Gajim, Psi or Tkabber. In that client open something like a "XML debug console", or sniff the traffic using tcpdump or ethereal. Then use that client to send the presence stanza. Later use your custom client, and compare the XML traffic.

Comment: Why don't you simply use Smack's MUC API?